# Throw exception when missing not nullable value in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json, .net-7.0

Having a `<nullable>enabled</nullable>` in project settings, having the following class

```
public class Car
{
    public required string Name { get; init; }
}
```

and deserializing it from string:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>("""{"Name": null}""");
```

Does not throw an exception

Because property is marked as not nullable, is it possible to configure STJ to throw in case of `null` value?

Comment: This is actually quite disappointing that it will by default assign null to a non-nullable string

Comment: It also works out of the box for Asp.Net Core 7 - then one gets a 400 and a validation error, so they have done something on top apparently

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I believe they have input validation as a part of binding pipeline, and I believe it happens after the deserialization, so it will struggle (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64187540/2501279)) with the non-nullable value types (which now potentially can be fixed with the `required`).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using .NET 7 and C# 11 by the looks from required modifier, you could try using [JsonRequiredAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonrequiredattribute?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) from System.Text.Json package.

Alternatively there is a similar option in Newtonsoft.Json package.

```
public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: `JsonRequiredAttribute` works exactly as `required` keyword from standpoint of `System.Text.Json`

Answer (score 3):

`required` as `JsonRequiredAttribute` results in `JsonTypeInfo.IsRequired` set to true and have same behaviour - throws only if the corresponding property is not present in the json ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties)):

> Starting in .NET 7, you can mark certain properties to signify that they must be present in the JSON payload for deserialization to succeed.

If you want to catch the properties being set to null you can leverage the ability to [customize the serialization contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts). You can start from the following:

```cs
static void ThrowNullableRequired(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
{
    if (jsonTypeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var property in jsonTypeInfo.Properties)
    {
        if (property is { IsRequired: true, PropertyType.IsValueType: false, Set: { } setter })
        {
            // not sure maybe should cache nullability checks
            NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
            var nullabilityInfo = context.Create(property.AttributeProvider as PropertyInfo);
            if (nullabilityInfo.WriteState is not NullabilityState.NotNull)
            {
                continue;
            }

            property.Set = (obj, val) =>
            {
                if (val is null)
                {
                    throw new JsonException($"null for required prop: {property.Name}");
                }

                setter(obj, val);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { ThrowNullableRequired }
    }
};
    
try
{
    var myClass1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(
        """
        {
            "Name":null,
            "Prefix":null
        }
        """, settings);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}

var car = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(
    """
        {
            "Name":"a",
            "Prefix":null
        }
        """, settings);
```

Comment: Rather than using `jsonTypeInfo.Type.GetProperty(property.Name)`, the [`JsonPropertyInfo.AttributeProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.attributeprovider) will actually be the `MemberInfo` of the member from which the `JsonPropertyInfo` was created (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77761)).  If you add an extension method `public static PropertyInfo? GetPropertyInfo(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as PropertyInfo);` you can get it directly and just check for null.

Comment: And for fields, you can do `static FieldInfo? GetFieldInfo(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as FieldInfo);`