# Required field validation doesn't work for nested polymorphic DTOs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, system.text.json

I'm using .NET 7 and having trouble getting required field validation to work correctly for nested polymorphic DTOs.

I have a controller method and DTO hierarchy like this:

```cs
    [HttpPost(Name = "PostTest")]
    public IActionResult PostTest([FromBody] ParentDto dto)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public class ParentDto
    {
        public ValueDto SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "type")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(ListValueDto), typeDiscriminator: "List")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(StringValueDto), typeDiscriminator: "String")]
    public abstract class ValueDto
    {
        // This correctly doesn't allow a null value
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListValueDto : ValueDto
    {
        // This allows null values - adding the [JsonRequired] attribute makes no difference either
        public List<string> Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class StringValueDto : ValueDto
    {
        // This also allows null values
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

It seems that any properties on non-top-level polymorphic classes don't get the same behaviour for null validation that top-level properties do. If I submit the following JSON to the `PostTest` endpoint, I get a HTTP 200 even though the required field `Value` on `StringValueDto` is `null`:

```json
{
  "someProperty": {
    "type": "String",
    "test": "test",
    "value": null
  }
}
```

If I omit the `test` property with this request, I correctly get a HTTP 400 response due to the required field being missing:

```json
{
  "someProperty": {
    "type": "String",
    "test": null,
    "value": "some string"
  }
}
```

And if I change `PostTest` to take `ValueDto` directly instead of a `ParentDto` then the required field validation on `ListValueDto.Value` and `StringValueDto.Value` works as expected. Adding `[JsonRequired]` has no effect.

How can I enforce properties on nested polymorphic DTOs to be required?

Comment: `[JsonRequierd]` only throws if the property is **missing**.  It doesn't throw if the property is present but null.  If you want System.Text.Json to throw for a present-but-null value, you can use a custom JsonTypeInfo modifier like the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74492877/3744182) by [Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) to [Throw exception when missing not nullable value in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74491487/3744182).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: My question is specifically about the inconsistency of a HTTP 400 being returned for `null` values on properties of polymorphic derived types vs non-polymorphic types. I only mentioned `[JsonRequired]` as something I'd tried - but it makes sense that it makes no difference. In the example I provided the `string` property on `ValueDto` results in a HTTP 400 when set to `null` but the `string` property on `StringValueDto` does not return HTTP 400 when set to `null` (violating the non-nullability of its type).