# Avoid Enum default value from DTO

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-webapi, dto, .net-7.0

I'm implementing WEB API and have a DTO like below.

```
public Class DataInput
{
        public List<DataPack> DataPacks { set; get; }
        public EleTypes EleType { get; set; }
}
```

This is the enum that above DTO is using.

```
public enum EleTypes
{
        firstEle,
        SecondEle,
        thiredEle
}
```

So My AppService has below method.

```
public async Task CreateDataSet(DataInput input)
{    
       Console.WriteLine(input.EleType);
       //My operation goes here    
}
```

With postman, I'm calling above end point and try to not to include **EleType** in the request payload. (Like below payload there is only DataPacks element.)

```
{
     "DataPacks": [ <my data going here> ] 
}
```

When this calls, the API hit successfully but it comes "firstEle" for **EleType** even if I did not set any value for EleType in postman request payload.

I want to avoid this. If it not comes any value for **EleType**, then it needs to be validated. Simply the method functioning should stop. Can any expert guide me how to validate such a situation?

Comment: You could make `EleTypes` nullable by using `EleTypes? EleType` and handle the null case in your action.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: .NET 7.0 is my FW

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with enums:

1. they are value types and are treated accordingly by serializer so if you don't provide a value default will be used. This can be handled by [`required` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required):

   ```
   public class DataInput 
   {
      public required EleTypes Type { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   or in earlier versions - by making property nullable and marking it with `RequiredAttribute` - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188108/2501279):

   ```
   public class DataInput 
   {
      [Required]
      public EleTypes? Type { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You can pass any valid integer (by default underlying type for enums is integer) and binder will validate it as a correct one. For this I would recommend to switch to [`FluentValidation` with it's build in enum validators](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#enum-validator) (or write your own validation leveraging `Enum.IsDefined<TEnum>` method).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code like below and the issue is solved.

```
public class DataInput
{
        public List<DataPack> DataPacks { set; get; }
        [Required]
        public EleTypes? EleType { get; set; }
}
```